# A Prism Xamarin Forms Mvvm Error

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, nuget, prism

I saw an Xamarin Evolve video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYRLcqG2BAY

Here's an unsolved reference

```
Public Class App:PrismApplication
{
  Public App()
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

Am I losing some reference that cause the PrismApplication error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have the proper NuGet packages installed.  Next make sure you have the proper using statements defined in your class.

Docs:  https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms/1-GettingStarted.md

NuGet Packages:  https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/DownloadandSetupPrism.md#nuget-packages

Samples (a little outdated):   https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms

Comment: Thanks! Brian!   I am using this as a very good tool but when you say no one really cares windows phones that hurts me lol or at least I care about UWP!  So, it seems that when I use xamarin.forms with uwp included, the app won't be able to build correctly.  So do prism support xamarin.forms based uwp?

Comment: Yes, Prism for XF support UWP.. Just make sure you are using the latest preview packages.  Prism.Unity.Form-pre-5